# Changing examples value in langchain chain

Tags: python, nlp, langchain, large-language-model, chatgpt-api

la

Assuming we have langchain chain `my_chain` created  using `my_schema` via:

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from kor.extraction import create_extraction_chain
from kor.nodes import Object, Text, Number
from langchain.chat.models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.llms import OpenAI

    schema = Object(
    id="bank_statement_info",
    description="bank statement information about a given person.",
    attributes=[
        Text(
            id="first_name",
            description="The first name of the person",
            examples=[("John Smith", "John")],
        ),
        Text(
            id="last_name",
            description="The last name of the person",
            examples=[("John Smith", "Smith")],
        ),
        Text(
            id="account_number",
            description="Account Number of the person in Bank statement.",
            examples=[("Account Number: 122-233-566-800", "122-233-566-800")],
        ),
        Text(
            id="address",
            description="address of the person in Bank statement.",
        ),
        Text(
            id="opening_balance",
            description="opening blance of the person in Bank statement.",
            examples=[("opening Balance: 245,800.00","245,800.00")]
        ),
        Text(
            id="closing_balance",
            description="closing blance of the person in Bank statement.",
            examples=[("Closing Balance: 591,800.00","591,800.00")]
        ),
    ],
    examples=[
        (
            """ya 231 Valley Farms Street
              FIRST Santa Monica, CA 90403 STATEMENT OF ACCOUNT
              CITIZENS __firstcitizensbank@domain.com
              BANK
              Account Number: 122-233-566-800
              Statement Date: 11/22/2019 Page 1 of 1
              Period Covered: 05/22/2019 to 11/22/2019
              Eric Nam Opening Balance: 175,800.00
              240 st, apt 15, hill road, Total Credit Amount: 510,000.00
              Baverly Hills, LA, 90209 Total Debit Amount: 94,000.00
              Closing Balance: 591,800.00
              Branch - Baverly Hills Account Type: Saving Account""",
            [
                {"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith", "account_number": '122-233-566-800',"address":"240 st, apt 15, hill road,Baverly Hills, LA, 90209",
                 "Closing Balance": "458,589.00","opening Balance": "800.00"},
                {"first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Doe", "age": '923-533-256-205',"address":"850 st, apt 82, hill road,Baverly Hills, New york, 82044",
                 "Closing Balance": "1000.00","opening Balance": "125,987.00"},
            ],
        )
    ],
    many=True,
)
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0, openai_api_key='', open_api_base='', model_kwargs={'engine: 'openai_gpt_4'}
my_chain = create_extraction_chain(llm, my_schema, encoder_or_encoder_class='json')
```

I want to have access to `examples` of `my_chain` after creating it. I tried to take access by accesing `my_chain.prompt` but afterwards could not get to examples. In particular, I would like to be able to  dynamically change the `examples` of `my_chain`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change examples in the schema dynamically, you can do that before you pass it in the `create_extraction_chain`. Something like this.

```
def extract(content: str, schema: dict):
    return create_extraction_chain(schema=schema, llm=llm).run(content)

schema = {...} # new examples
extracted_content = extract(content, schema)
```